# Creating new jnlp/java web start jenkins agent using ruby API

Tags: ruby, jenkins, chef-infra

I want to create a new jnlp slave in my master using ruby API without the need for any alteration in jenkins master gui.

I've been searching the web for the past 4 hours with no luck.

this is my recipe so far...
I don't like this, because using jenkinsapi with username and password is deprecated, and using public key require me to login the gui and add a public key (and as I mentioned, I want everything done from the api/cli)

```
include_recipe 'sap-java'
node.set['java']['set_etc_environment'] = true

matchMaster = node['jenkins-slave-ws']['master'].match(/https?:\/\/(.+):(\d+)\//)
masterHost = matchMaster[1]
masterPort = matchMaster[2]

node['litc-jenkins-slave-ws']['slave_name']

chef_gem 'jenkins_api_client'
require 'jenkins_api_client'
@client = JenkinsApi::Client.new(:server_ip => masterHost,
         :username => 'uname', :password => 'pass')
# The following call will return the version of Jenkins instance
puts @client.exec_cli("version")
```

Comment: And how do you think you could add the key without intervention on the jenkins master itself ? Best bet would be to configure a slave, have it generate it's key, register it in node attributes and have chef run on the amster node to allow this new slave...

Comment: There is no way to add the key... but for my use case working with no user or password requirement is good... managed to solve this eventually

Comment: Unfortunately Jenkins API auth is kind of a tire fire. You can check out my super old jenkins cookbook (github.com/poise/jenkins) to see how I created API users without touching the GUI but it was so hacky I gave up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was very close
this works:

```
xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<slave>\n  
<name>#{node['litc-jenkins-slave-ws']['slave_name']}</name>\n  
<description></description>\n  
<remoteFS>c:\\jenkins\\jenkins-slave\\.</remoteFS>\n 
<numExecutors>1</numExecutors>\n
<mode>NORMAL</mode>\n
<retentionStrategy class=\"hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy$Always\"/>\n  
<launcher class=\"hudson.slaves.JNLPLauncher\"/>\n  <label></label>\n  
<nodeProperties/>\n</slave>"

chef_gem 'jenkins_api_client'
require 'jenkins_api_client'
@client = JenkinsApi::Client.new(server_ip: masterHost,
                                 username: 'uname', password: 'pass')

@client.node.create_dumb_slave(
    name: node['litc-jenkins-slave-ws']['slave_name'],
    slave_host: '10.10.10.10',
    private_key_file: '/root/.ssh/id_rsa',
    executors: 10,
    labels: 'slave, ruby'
)

@client.node.post_config(node['litc-jenkins-slave-ws']['slave_name'], xml)
```

Comment: Are you also able to get the JNLP URL from the api somehow? Working through a very similar scenario here.